# Cannot find monotouch assembly in Xamarin Studio

Tags: xamarin.ios, xamarin

Higuys, I'm new to Xamarin and I'm in trouble here. I added an `Empty C# Library Application` to my solution in Xamarin Studio but could not find the assembly `monotouch` to add reference to. Meanwhile my iOS and Android project can see that assembly in the list.

I am using Xamarin Studio 4.2.5

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the "iOS Library Project" template.

Comment: I encountered the same problem. Can not find the monotouch.dll in an "iOS Library Project" if I use Unified API. The monotouch.dll is only available in Classic (32bit) Projects